# How to get data from Excel sheet to VB 2008 program?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, excel, vba

I am creating a program which requires some Data from an Existing Excel file.
I want to show few Cell's values to VB program message box created in a form.
How can I get it in VB-2008?
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything out..?

Comment: please post the code you have tried and tell us what errors your are getting

Answer (score 1):

I believe "TABLE_NAME" in the following example will be the name of the first Sheet in the Excel file.

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Data

    Private Function getExcelDataTable() As Data.DataTable
                Dim dt As New Data.DataTable

                Dim fileName As String = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/MyExcel.xls")


                Dim xConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1"""
                Dim objXConn As New OleDbConnection(xConnStr)
                Try
                    objXConn.Open()
                    Dim dtSchema As Data.DataTable
                    dtSchema = objXConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
                    Dim sheet1 As String = dtSchema.Rows(0).Item("TABLE_NAME")
                    Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & sheet1 & "]", objXConn)
                    Dim objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                    ' retrieve the Select command for the Spreadsheet
                    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = objCommand
                    objDataAdapter.Fill(dt)
                    objXConn.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    objXConn.Close()
                    Throw ex
                End Try

                Return dt
            End Function
```